# Pitfalls when sharing IDbConnection in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a service that use several repositories. I want them all to use the same transaction so that, if anything goes wrong, I can rollback the transactions and nothing is left in an invalid state in the database.

I've created a connection factory that returns the same connection to all clients.

```
public IDbConnection Connection => _db ?? (_db = _factory.OpenDbConnection());
```

Repositories takes the class holding this property as a constructor argument. This seemingly works, and enables them to use the same connection, and I can manage the transaction on the outer level. Both the connection factory and its clients are registered in IoC with `ReuseScope.Request`.

I am wondering though, are there any pitfalls to this?

What happens if someone™ starts using async/await with this shared connection? Do I have to ensure that the connection is never shared across threads? (I was thinking about storing it in a ThreadLocal inside the connection factory).

Anything else?

I'm sorry for this kind of vague question, but I believe this must be a quite common use case.

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET's `IDbConnection` resource instance is not thread safe and should never be used in multiple threads. Typically each Thread would retrieve its own pooled DB Connection from the Db connection factory.

Whilst `async/await` can continue on a different thread, they're not executed concurrently so the same DB Connection can be used as it doesn't get used by multiple threads at the same time.

When I do use repositories they would be responsible for logical units of functionality, (never per-table which I consider an anti-pattern forcing unnecessary friction and abstraction penalties), so I'd rarely have transactions spanning multiple repositories, if I did I'd make it explicit and pass the same DB connection to each repository within an explicit DB transaction scope, e.g:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    using (var dbTrans = Db.OpenTransaction())
    {
        MyRepository1.Something(Db, request.Id);
        MyRepository2.Something(Db, request.Id);
        //....

        dbTrans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm aware that this is not an ideal approach. The repositories aren't per-table, but the operation performed by the service involves a lot of different parts.

Comment: I take a similar approach as @Mythz mentioned.  I've built common back-end functionality that is used by 2-3 different front-end methods (web, internal management, periodic background processor, etc.).  In each case I pass in the `IDbConnection` to the common component, so it maintains transnational consistency.  I use MSSQL server, and in some cases I've had to pre-lock rows or tables to avoid deadlocks.